# Real schematic vs. ideal schematic, real components (R, L, C) vs. ideal components

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design

I have come to a realization that throughout what I have been taught about electronic components and circuit schematics, there is a hidden side that is rarely talked about and not ever discussed in detail.

This is the difference between the ideal schematic that shows the intended current flow with ideal components that follow rules like \$V = I \cdot R\$, \$I = C \frac{dv}{dt}\$, \$V = L\frac{di}{dt}\$, a circuit where the connecting wires have no resistance.

The real world is completely different and the hidden aspects manifest themself at high frequencies when the circuit is not "lumped" anymore where we realize that resistors have frequency responses, capacitors have inductances, and inductors have resistances, PCB tracks have inductances and also capacitances. WOW!!!

What I wish from to do is to have a book/website/app note that will cover these real properties and the "parasitic" effects in detail and explain their origins. To be more specific: Where can I learn about the "real" R, L, C and on a separate note the "real" schematics that show what exactly is there on the board with all the parasitic and other usually ignored details. Is there a book or app note that may teach me how to think in terms of real world components and PCB design issues and explain origins on this "realness"?

Comment: R, L and C - a resistor has a bit of everything and so does an inductor and a capacitor. There are no other mechanisms at play until you get into transmission lines. Take a look at specs for decent caps and see what frequency these turn tail on you and behave like inductors. Ask your self what does self-resonant frequency mean for an inductor - it's all about R, L and C and their various proportions.

Comment: This is a good question, but unfortunately, I think too broad to answer in this format. Some fields care more about these non-ideal behaviors than others, and generally they become more relevant with increasing frequency. So, pick up any book on RF or high-speed digital design.

Comment: hmm, just the thing I need

Comment: The devil is always in the detail - from a teaching/writing point of view I  always try to simplify the model to enable the student/reader to progress (that 'aha' moment) Imagine how confusing it would be if you started learning about a resistor only to be told it was also an inductor and had parasitic capacitance etc, etc. Its the same with any subject, not just electronics, as you progress you modify and refine your internal models until they give a better match to reality - its an iterative process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may sound obvious, but I think it's actually an answer to your question:

- The best books to learn about effects for high-frequency design are books on high-frequency design.
- The best books to learn about effects of high-power transmission are books on high-power transmission.
- The best books to learn about sub-micron integrated circuit effects
  are books about sub-micron integrated circuit design.

Most of the effects you talk about are those seen at higher frequencies -- radio, and fast digital. Thus, I would recommend books on HF circuit implementation as a good start.

Answer (score 12):

This may seem an evasive answer, but there is no 'realness'. Everything we use is an abstraction, which is an approximation of the the lower abstraction underneath it.

This goes all the way to down to Schrödinger equations that describe the world perfectly as far as we know today (which probably just means that there are lower layers that we don't know about yet), but which we can't solve for any but the most simple situations.

The trick is to know the abstraction that you are using, to know when it falls apart, and avoid such situations.

It is for instance much easier to work with ideal logical gates (no delay, no power used, ideal waveforms, etc) and to make sure that they

- are used well below their maximum speed
- are adequately powered and decoupled
- are connected by wires that are short compared to the waveforms and switching times

For the much rarer cases, or the much smaller parts of your design, where these conditions are not met, you must look much more careful and see the logical gates and their interconnecting wires as sources with a certain impedance, tranmission lines, and you might need receiver sides that have a well-known impedance (much lower than you would prefer in the 'ideal' situation). Yuk.

Most designers can cope with one or a few abstraction levels. I can deal with all kinds of layers in software. In hardware I can deal with logic, gate delays, and I can apply enough rules of thumb to avoid getting in all sorts of problems at this level. One level down I can make good guesses, but I must leave the real work to the experts at that level (who should probably not diddle too much with the higher software layers that I am more familiar with).

If I want a taste of the real deep down level I can always ask my wife about interactions of bosons as described by path integrals. Probably a much more accurate description of the physical world, but not very applicable to everyday electronics.

The unofficial bible of electronics (Horowitz & Hill) does an adequate job of explaining a few layers of abstraction that are useful in electronics design, including the limitations of these abstractions.

[image]
(thanks Phil - I LOVE xkcd!)

Comment: https://xkcd.com/435/